# Ajax call not updating template django

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

**Below are the details. I am able to get updated "questions_in_topic" variable in views when select option is changed i.e. ajax call is made.  Ajax call is updating the "questions_in_topic" variable based on selected value in dropdown. But these changes are not reflected in template. i.e. on template, I still get old values.**

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^interview/add/questions/library', recruiter_views.add_question_library, name='add_question_library'),
```

**views.py**

```
def add_question_library(request):
    question_topics = QuestionTopic.objects.values('question_id__description', 'topic_id__name','question_id','topic_id').order_by('topic_id__name','question_id__description')
    all_topics = Topic.objects.all()
    questions_in_topic = QuestionTopic.objects.values('question_id__description').order_by('question_id__description')

    if request.is_ajax():
        if 'topicId' in request.POST:
            print("xx")
            questions_in_topic = QuestionTopic.objects.filter(topic_id=request.POST['topicId']).values('question_id__description').order_by('question_id__description')
        else:
            print("yy")
            questions_in_topic = QuestionTopic.objects.values('question_id__description').order_by('question_id__description')

    print(questions_in_topic)
    context = { 'question_topics': question_topics, 'all_topics': all_topics,'questions_in_topic':questions_in_topic,}
    return render(request, 'recruiter/add_question_library.html', context)
```

**add_question_library.html**

```
<select id="topic" name="topic_list" class="form-control topic_select">
              {% for topic in all_topics %}
               <option data-topic="{{topic.id}}" value="{{topic.name}}">{{topic.name}}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>    
<ul class="list-unstyled">
            {% for x in questions_in_topic %}
            <li class="list-unstyled">{{ x.question_id__description }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

**ajax**

```
var topicId = $(".topic_select option:selected").attr("data-topic");
    $(".topic_select").change(function(){
      var topicId = $(".topic_select option:selected").attr("data-topic");
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{% url 'recruiter:add_question_library' %}",
          data: {
            topicId: topicId,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
          },
          success: function(){
              // alert("Showing questions from topic " + topicId);
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: what's the part of the DOM that you want to replace after the ajax call?

Comment: <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {% for x in questions_in_topic %}
            <li class="list-unstyled">{{ x.question_id__description }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>

Comment: you just need to retrieve the response in success : `success: function(response){ response is here`

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 2):

With the request coming from view after the ajax call, you can do this:

```
// stuff
success: function(response){
   // $("taget").replaceWith($("target",response));
   $("ul.list-unstyled").replaceWith($("ul.list-unstyled",response));
}
```

You may have multiple `ul.list-unstyled` in your project, I suggest that you add a unique ID to the list.

Comment: In that case please be so kind as to mark the answer as correct.